# SPARQL result format Join and convert rows into columns

Tags: sparql

Hi I have this schema

```
<product> dprop:title "title"en; dprop:description "description:en.
```

And offer schema is

```
<offer> dprop:condition 1; dprop:proce 123. # condition 1 is for new offer and 0 is used offer
```

And relation between product and offer is

```
<offer> oprop:isOfferOf <product>
```

So now I have list of product ids and I want to get against these products in single row

```
0:- Product Id
1:- Minim price in new offers
2:- Minim price in used offers
3:- Id of that offer which have  minim price with condition used
4:- Id of that offer which have  minim price with condition new
5:- Id of that offer which have  minim price with condition used
6:- Total counts for New offers against each product
7:- Total counts for Used offers against each product
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT ?minPrice  ?cond  ?newOffs  ?usedOffs  ?pid  ?newOid  ?usedOid
    WHERE {
      {
        SELECT ?pid ?cond ( sample(?offid) AS ?oid )
          ( MIN(?price) AS ?minPrice )
          (sum(?newIncrement) AS ?newOffs)
          (sum(?oldIncrement) AS ?usedOffs)
        WHERE{
          ?pid ^mod:isOfferOf ?offid. ?offid dprop:condition ?cond; dprop:price ?price.
          BIND (if( ?cond = 1, 0, 1) AS ?newIncrement).
          BIND (if( ?cond = 1, 1, 0) AS ?oldIncrement).
          VALUES ?pid { prod:Rl5RVl5R  prod:Rl5RVl5Q prod:Rl5RVl5W prod:Rl5RVl5Y prod:Rl5RVl5U }
        } GROUP BY ?pid ?cond
      }
      BIND(IF(?cond = 0, ?oid , ?null) AS ?usedOid).
      BIND(IF(?cond = 1, ?oid , ?null) AS ?newOid).
    }
```

Now in my query i have `productID condition(new/1) offerId(new) and minPrice(from new offers only )` same duplicate row but with used offer data(id, minPrice, counts ) I want to combine both rows like `group by ?pid`
Here is [live Query](http://dydra.com/nauman/question-prod-offers/@query#secondversionquery) and result [Preview](http://dydra.com/nauman/question-prod-offers/secondversionquery.html) of my query.

Comment: This question doesn't include enough information *within* the question to be answerable.  Please provide minimal data *in the question*, and the query you've attempted so far.

Comment: Hi @joshua taylor. Here is my [Query](http://dydra.com/nauman/question-prod-offers/secondversionquery.html) i have some blank values as you can see in my query. So

Comment: I don't know what dydra.com is;  please edit your question (the edit link) if you can provide more information.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaTaylor Sorry for incomplete comment. [Live Query](http://dydra.com/nauman/question-prod-offers/@query#secondversionquery) I want to get ```  pid price_with_cond_0 price_with_1 newOfferId usedOfferId finalNewCounts(total new offers) finalUsedCounts  ```. Thank you

Comment: Code is not readable in comments.  **Use the edit link under your question to update the question**.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i updated my question.i hope it will help you to understand my requirements.

Comment: Please be sure to proofread your edit.  It doesn't show everything you'd expect it to.  E.g., you posted `<offer> dprop:isOfferOf <product>`, but only `dprop:isOfferOf` appears (since the other parts are interpreted as malformed HTML).  Even so, your question does not contain enough information;  links to external sites are not helpful---you need to post the query and data *here*, on Stack Overflow, **in the question**.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaTaylor I tried my best to explain my problem. I hope this update will clear my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84869/discussion-between-9me-and-joshua-taylor).